# Finding all permutations by swapping (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, list, permutation, linear-algebra, swap

First let me say that I am an absolute beginner to MATLAB. I have been given an assignment to generate a matrix "A" containing all the permutations of a number "n" number by swapping adjacent numbers.

I have been stuck with this for two days and this is as close to an answer as i have come:

```
X=[1:n]
A(1,:)=X;
for j=0:n
for i=n:-1:2
    if  X(i)==(n-j)
            temp=X(i);
            X(i)=X(i-1);
            X(i-1)=temp;
            A=[A; X];   

    end
   end
end
A
```

This works for n=3. I was wondering if there is anything that could be done to fix this code or if I should try something completely different.

**EDIT**

This is a second attempt that has some notion of direction. Problem is that this script only follows one "track". det(I(:,X)) tells me if previous permutation is odd/even and if the integer should be swapped to the right or to the left. I want it to do both!

```
n=input('n: ')
X=[1];
for i=2:n
u=length(X);
I = speye(u);
if det(I(:,X))>0
    X=[X i];
    X
    X([i-1 i])=X([i i-1]);
    X
else
    X=[i X];
    X
    for j=1:i-1
    X([j j+1])=X([j+1 j]);
    X
    end
    end
end
```

Comment: If you want to use a specific algorithm, please write it out exactly and then we can help with implementing it if neccesary.

Comment: What do you mean by "swapping adjacent numbers"? Can you give a small example?

Comment: I am supposed to use the Steinhaus-Johnson-Trotter algorithm, which I understand uses swapping.

Comment: You might have some luck if you look for information on the [Steinhaus–Johnson–Trotter algorithm](http://tropenhitze.wordpress.com/2010/01/25/steinhaus-johnson-trotter-permutation-algorithm-explained-and-implemented-in-java/) - this tutorial is a quite nice and clear explanation of how it works.

Comment: The first big problem that I encounter when trying to compare your code to the algorithm, is that you don't seem to keep track of the direction of each number.

Comment: Could you tell me a way to keep track of the direction?

Comment: You could keep a separate vector with something like -1 for left and +1 for right (multiply by -1 to swap direction). I suggest you start by writing a helper function that finds the largest mobile number given a permutation and a set of directions.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should take advantage of what matlab has to offer, and let it do the work for you.

Here is all that it takes:

```
P = perms(v)
```

Comment: I would if I wasn't asked to find a way to do it by swapping adjacent numbers